# Microsoft Graph API get a list of Users by ids

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I need to call Microsoft Graph API to get a list of users by a list of user id's.

And in the response, each User should include her Groups' id.

Anyone knows how to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to expand `memberOf` and use casting for `group`. In `Filter`, use `in` operator and specify at most 15 users ids. 15 is the limit.

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var result = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string []{ "memberOf/microsoft.graph.group($select=id)" };
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "id in ('{user-id1}','{user-id2}','{user-id3}','{user-id4}','{user-id5}','{user-id6}','{user-id7}','{user-id8}','{user-id9}','{user-id10}','{user-id11}','{user-id12}','{user-id13}','{user-id14}','{user-id15}')";
});
```

In `Expand`, I'm using `$select` to return only id of the group.

If you have more than 15 users, you will need to make several calls.

I suppose, you are using [Graph C# SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for... it works.. thx